# "Extern" object problem: error: Id returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, qt

I tried to make snake game. It almost done but I have a problem with writing Score increasing function. I am using "extern" command in order to use a function into another class but Qt gives me an error

I can't try anything because I didn't understand the problem. (there is no problem with collinding_items codes. It can run without score. The problem is about "extern" command)

main.cpp

```
Score *score = new Score();

scene->addItem(score);
```

Score.h

class Score: public QGraphicsTextItem
{

public:

```
Score(QGraphicsItem *parents=0);

void increase();

int getScore();
```

private:

int Gamescore=0;
};

Score.cpp

```
void Score::increase()

{

Gamescore=+20;

setPlainText(QString("Score: ") + QString::number(Gamescore));

}

int Score::getScore()

{

return Gamescore;

}
```

Snake.cpp

```
extern Score *score;


 QList<QGraphicsItem *> colliding_items = collidingItems();

        for(int i=0, n=colliding_items.size(); i<n; ++i)
        {
            if(typeid(*colliding_items[i])==typeid (Fruit))
            {
                scene()->removeItem(colliding_items[i]);
                delete(colliding_items[i]);

                score->increase();
            }
        }
```

Undefined reference to 'score'

error: Id returned 1 exit status

(File not found collect2.exe)

Comment: Is the `main.cpp` code snippet the *complete* source file `main.cpp`? Where is that part from? Do you define `score` as a local variable inside a function? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: main.cpp has a lot of codes. I just add related code to my questions. Because before adding score, everything works very well. But the actual problem is I cant call a function of a class into another class by using object. (Sorry for my english)

Comment: @Magic_Key provide a [MRE] if you want help, otherwise your question is off-topic and could be closed. Read [ask], [answer] and pass the [tour] if you have not done so.

Comment: I translated my codes turkish to english. I made some mistake and I corrected them. I read 'How to Ask'. I understood that I have to write all my codes to be able to explain my problem. But my question is simple. Anyway, I will search how 'extern' is used with detail. If i cant find a solution, I will share all my codes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It derives from usage of 'extern' command. It must be used as global. You can see the part of my code below.

Score.h

```
class Score: public QGraphicsTextItem
{
public:
    Puan(QGraphicsItem *parents=0);

    void increase();
    int getScore();

private:
    int Gamescore;
};
```

Snake.cpp

```
extern Score *scoring;

Snake::Snake()
{
}

void Show()
{
    scoring->increase();
}
```

If I used extern as global then I can use the increase() function of Score.cpp in the Snake.cpp